# Rails ActiveRecord joins with multiple tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a Category Model which belongs to Offer Model through a third Model OfferCategory. I also have a similar association for PlumCake Model which is associated to Category model through PlumCakeCategory Model.

Category:

```
has_many :offer_categories, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :category
has_many :offers, through: :offer_categories, source: :offer
has_many :plum_cake_categories, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :category
has_many :plum_cakes, through: :plum_cake_categories, source: :plum_cake
```

Offer:

```
has_many :offer_categories, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :offer
has_many :categories, through: :offer_categories, source: :category, dependent: :destroy
```

OfferCategory:

```
belongs_to :offer
belongs_to :category
```

PlumCake:

```
 has_many :plum_cake_categories, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :plum_cake
has_many :categories, through: :plum_cake_categories, source: :category, dependent: :destroy
```

PlumCakeCategory:

```
belongs_to :plum_cake
belongs_to :category
```

and a similar association for category/plumcakes as well.

Now I want to get all categoires that the selected offers and plumcakes has. The following query gives me the list of categories that the eligible_offer_ids offers has.

```
Category.joins(:offer_categories).where(offer_categories: { offer_id: eligible_offer_ids })
```

I can fire a similar query for plum_cake and get uniq categoires of these two queries.

```
cat1 = Category.joins(:offer_categories).where(offer_categories: { offer_id: eligible_offer_ids })
cat2 = Category.joins(:plum_cake_categories).where(plum_cake_categories: { plum_cake_id: eligible_plum_cake_ids })
(cat1 + cat2).uniq
```

But Is there a way I get the same result((cat1 + cat2).uniq) in a single query?

Comment: Category.distinct.joins(:offer_categories, :plum_cake_categories).where(offer_categories: { offer_id: eligible_offer_ids }).where(plum_cake_categories: { plum_cake_id: eligible_plum_cake_ids })

Comment: @AniketShivamTiwari The problem with the above query is that it is executed one by one in AND condition. I want OR values.

Comment: Can you add the missing models to your question? To see their relationships.

Comment: @SebastianPalma done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you don't to want change your structure:

```
Category.left_outer_joins(:offer_categories, :plum_cake_categories).where(offer_categories: { offer_id: eligible_offer_ids }).or(Category.left_outer_joins(:offer_categories, :plum_cake_categories).where(plum_cake_categories: { plum_cake_id: eligible_plum_cake_ids })).uniq
```

Comment: left_outer_joins seems to be working. Kindly update your answer with left_outer_joins.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you use rails STI(single table inheritance) you can easily implement your functionality.

if your structure be somthing like following:

```
class Category
  has_many :offer_categories, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :category
  has_many :offers, through: :offer_categories, source: :offer
  has_many :plum_cake_categories, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :category
  has_many :plum_cakes, through: :plum_cake_categories, source: :plum_cake
  has_many :sub_categories
end

class SubCategory
  belongs_to :offer
  belongs_to :plum_cake
  belongs_to :category
end

class OfferCategory < SubCategory
  validate_presence_of :offer_id
end

class PlumCakeCategory < SubCategory
  validate_presence_of :plum_cake_id
end
```

your query will be:

```
Category.joins(:sub_categories).where(sub_categories: { offer_id: eligible_offer_ids }).or(Category.joins(:sub_categories).where(sub_categories: { plum_cake_id: eligible_plum_cake_ids }))
```

[STI documentation](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Inheritance.html)

Comment: I understand the logic. But anything without modifying the DB structure?